# Showing irreducible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

Let $A$ be a matrix which is irreducible, so there exists no permutation matrix $P$ such that $P^{T}AP$ is upper block triangular. Let $B$ a matrix for which $A_{ij}\leq B_{ij} \leq 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $0<A_{ii}<B_{ii}$. How can I show that $B$ is irreducible as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Consider, e.g.,
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}\quad\text{and}\quad B=\pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}.
$$
Both $A$ and $B$ satisfy the given conditions but $B$ is reducible.

It would be true if you replaced "$A_{ij}\leq B_{ij}\leq 0$ for $i\neq j$" by "$B_{ij}\leq A_{ij}\leq 0$ for $i\neq j$". This is easy: the only way how to make an irreducible matrix reducible is to set some off-diagonal entries to zero.

Comment: So matrix $B$ isn't a M-matrix? (M-matrix is a K-matrix which is irreducible)

Comment: @RoosJansen A matrix does not need to be irreducible to be an M-matrix. (I'm not really sure what is a K-matrix.) Usually, an M-matrix is a Z-matrix which does satisfy one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix#Equivalences) conditions.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a hint to proof that B is a M-matrix? (because I thought K-matrix+irreducible implies M-matrix, where a K-matrix is a Z-matrix with diagonal elements bigger than 0)

Comment: @RoosJansen If $A$ is real symmetric, then "being an M-matrix" and "being positive definite" are equivalent terms. There are lots of K-matrices which are symmetric but not positive definite (take a symmetric K-matrix with "large" negative off-diagonal entries like $A=\pmatrix{1&-2\\-2&1}$ is a K-matrix, irreducible, but not an M-matrix).

Comment: @RoosJansen Otherwise, taking an M-matrix $A$ and making its off-diagonals "less negative" and the diagonal "more positive" most likely won't change the "M-matricity" of the result. You might ask a new question on that if you like.